# Keyboard and mouse not working correctly. I am curious how to even start troubleshooting this

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse

I have an HP Pavilion dv6-7020 laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.  My keyboard and mouse have been sporadically messing up.  When not functioning properly, I can type my password on the login page, but I can't hit enter. I have to click "sign in."  Then once I log in, the built in track pad doesn't work, but a USB mouse does.  However, the built in keyboard almost entirely doesn't work, nor does a USB keyboard.  Also the on screen keyboard doesn't work.  However, if I click on "Activities" on the upper left hand side of the screen, I can type in the search box, but I can't use back space.  If I try to type while using Chrome, for instance, almost nothing happens, but if I hit the space bar then a menu pops up.  However, randomly the keyboard will start working. Like right now.  However it's done this 3 or 4 times today, so sometime soon I'm sure it will stop working again. I'm at a loss to know what could be causing this behavior.  Is there any troubleshooting you would recommend?  Probably related is that several times today I have gotten a pop up message saying "system error" or something similar, and asking if I would like to send a report.

UPDATE:  Sorry I haven't updated this.  It was rather difficult to troubleshoot during the times no input devices were working.  I eventually noticed during one of the stretches when the keyboard was working that evtest seemed to be registering keystrokes correctly.  Evtest also listed my keyboard, but not my nonfunctional touchpad.  I then physically disconnected the touchpad and the laptop has been working flawlessly all day. So my guess is that the touchpad was experiencing a hardware malfunction and that causing the problem.

Comment: Did you check /var/log for errors?

Comment: My first step would be looking at the details of the error message (should be displayed when you choose to report the problem). Then, I would run `xev` to 1) see if a broken input device floods the X server with input events and 2) if X even receives the keystrokes. If it does not, I'd run `evtest` to find out if maybe the kernel receives the key events but doesn't produce the correct symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. This computer is at my lab so I'll try these tomorrow and see if I can get more information.